# Creating a CXF proxy client for WCF file upload

Tags: wcf, file-upload, cxf

I'm trying to create a WCF service (.Net 4.5 in VS2012) for file uploads that can be consumed by clients in other languages, Java (using CXF) in particular. I've got the WCF side of things working great from .Net clients, but am having some issues on the CXF side.

When I try to generate the proxy in CXF from the WSDL through Eclipse (4.2/Juno), I'm getting an exception that prevents the proxy from being created:

```
wsdl2java -client -d C:\Users\Ryan\workspace\WcfProxy\.cxftmp/src -classdir C:\Users\Ryan\workspace\WcfProxy\build\classes -p http://tempuri.org/=org.tempuri -impl -validate -exsh false -dns true -dex true -wsdlLocation http://localhost:10186/UploadFile.svc?wsdl -verbose -defaultValues -fe jaxws -db jaxb -wv 1.1 http://localhost:10186/UploadFile.svc?wsdl
wsdl2java - Apache CXF 2.7.0


WSDLToJava Error: Schema Error : src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ns0:StreamBody' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Schema Error : src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ns0:StreamBody' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.validateSchema(JAXBDataBinding.java:914)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.addSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:586)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:392)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:603)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:248)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:142)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:300)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ns0:StreamBody' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.validateSchema(JAXBDataBinding.java:909)
... 10 more
```

My WCF service contract is as follows:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IUploadFile

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub UploadFile(ByVal remoteFile As RemoteFile)

    <OperationContract()>
    Function DownloadFile() As RemoteFile

End Interface
```

My WCF message contract (`RemoteFile`) is as follows:

```
<MessageContract()> _
Public Class RemoteFile
    Implements IDisposable

    <MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)> _
    Public FileName As String

    <MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)> _
    Public Length As Long

    <MessageBodyMember(Order:=1)> _
    Public FileByteStream As System.IO.Stream

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        If FileByteStream IsNot Nothing Then
            FileByteStream.Close()
            FileByteStream = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

My WCF service configuration is as follows:

```
...
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding"
        transferMode="Streamed"
        messageEncoding="Mtom"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864">
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="UploadServiceBehavior" name="Server.UploadFile">
      <endpoint address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="FileTransferServicesBinding"
            contract="Server.IUploadFile" />
    </service>
  </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="UploadServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
...
```

My WSDL is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="UploadFile" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadFile_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization/>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:10186/UploadFile.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:10186/UploadFile.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"/>
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:10186/UploadFile.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFile">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RemoteFile"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFile_Headers">
    <wsdl:part name="FileName" element="tns:FileName"/>
    <wsdl:part name="Length" element="tns:Length"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IUploadFile_DownloadFile_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:portType name="IUploadFile">
    <wsdl:operation name="UploadFile">
        <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IUploadFile/UploadFile" name="RemoteFile" message="tns:RemoteFile"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DownloadFile">
        <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IUploadFile/DownloadFile" message="tns:IUploadFile_DownloadFile_InputMessage"/>
        <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IUploadFile/DownloadFileResponse" name="RemoteFile" message="tns:RemoteFile"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadFile" type="tns:IUploadFile">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_IUploadFile_policy"/>
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="UploadFile">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IUploadFile/UploadFile" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input name="RemoteFile">
            <soap:header message="tns:RemoteFile_Headers" part="FileName" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:RemoteFile_Headers" part="Length" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DownloadFile">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IUploadFile/DownloadFile" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="RemoteFile">
            <soap:header message="tns:RemoteFile_Headers" part="FileName" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:RemoteFile_Headers" part="Length" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="UploadFile">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadFile" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IUploadFile">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:10186/UploadFile.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Obviously the exception indicates it is having an issue creating the stream body type of the message, but does anyone see what I'm doing wrong or need to change to be able to generate a CXF proxy for this WCF service?

**EDIT** Added WSDL to original post.

Comment: I think it would be helpful, if you would post your WSDL.